# Swift, Reverse only letters

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, objective-c, reverse

I face the problem. When i try to reverse only letters in swift by using Two pointer pattern its actually doing swap instead.
sample - Test 123 String
2 pointer output - gnir 123 tStseT
expected output - tseT 123 gnirtS
Can somebody advice the method, or give example of code pls.?

```
func reverseOnlyLetters(_ S: String) -> String {
   
    var a = Array(S.unicodeScalars)
    
    var i = 0
    var j = a.count - 1
    
    while i < j {
        while !CharacterSet.letters.contains(a[i]) && i < j { i += 1 }
        while !CharacterSet.letters.contains(a[j]) && i < j { j -= 1 }
        
        let t = a[i]
        a[i] = a[j]
        a[j] = t
        i += 1
        j -= 1
    }
    
    var ret = ""
    a.forEach({ ret += String(Character(UnicodeScalar($0))) })
    return ret
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
func reverseOnlyLetters(_ S: String) -> String {
    let components = S.components(separatedBy: " ")
    let reversedComponents = components.map { Int($0) == nil ? String($0.reversed()) : $0 }
    return reversedComponents.joined(separator: " ")
}
```

if it still not correct, please give me more infomation